# error while build in jenkins; error whilw instaling nuget packages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jenkins, build, msbuild, nuget

### Heading

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine -Version 6.0.0
```

Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Version'.
At line:1 char:35

- Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine -Version 6.0.0
- ```
                                ~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Package], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage